# Query to find ASCII equivalent to 65,67,84 in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle and Pl/Sql:-
I want to find ASCII equivalent to 65,67 and 84.
Please suggest me the query.

```sql
SELECT ASCII('M') FROM DUAL;
```

From above query,I didn't get the proper answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT CHR(65) from dual
```

etc.